# How to make DKMS pass the right ARCH to 'make'?

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, dkms

I'm trying to use DKMS to build a module. My problem is that I cannot seem to make DKMS pass the right ARCH to 'make'. It keeps using the architecture of the my OS's kernel which is armv7l. But there's no map
/usr/src/linux/arch/armv7l
It needs to look inside
/usr/src/linux/arch/arm

I have tried passing -a arm,  -k 4.4.21-v7+/arm as arguments to 'dkms build', but it doesn't pass that down to 'make'. Adding BUILD_EXCLUSIVE_ARCH="arm" to /usr/src/rtl8812AU-4.3.14/dkms.conf also makes no difference.

> **sudo dkms build -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION} -k 4.4.21-v7+/arm**
>
> Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
>
> Building module:
>   cleaning build area....
>   'make'....(bad exit status: 2)
>   Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.21-v7+ (arm)
>   Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build/make.log for more information.
>
> **cat /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build/make.log**
>
> DKMS make.log for rtl8812AU-4.3.14 for kernel 4.4.21-v7+ (arm)
>   Thu Sep 29 16:36:07 UTC 2016
>   make **ARCH=armv7l** CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.21-v7+/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build  modules
>   make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux'
>   Makefile:606: arch/armv7l/Makefile: No such file or directory
>   make[1]: No rule to make target 'arch/armv7l/Makefile'.  Stop.
>   make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux'
>   Makefile:1576: recipe for target 'modules' failed
>   make: [modules] Error 2

How to solve this?
Thank you already

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem on a Raspberry Pi 2 with Ubuntu Mate (16.04) by symlinking the arm directory:

```
sudo ln -s arm armv7l
```

Dirty hack, but it works :)

Comment: I marked it as the right answer, but I actually didn't test it. I'll just trust your answer based on your reputation. :P

Comment: It worked on my machine :D Since it's apparently just the folder name which is the problem and not an architectural incompatibility, it should Just Work (tm). For my own use case I ended up using a different driver which was not installed via DKMS. Seems like there aren't too many of such drivers around (yet).

Comment: Did not work for me :( I'm trying to build an RTL8192eu driver on the Odroud XU3 with the official 4.9 kernel. I could change the 'make' command with ```ARCH=arm``` but later it still fails with ```Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.9.28-38 (armv7l)``` =/

Comment: worked for me in order to build rtl8821au-dkms-git aur package on a rpi3 with archlinux arm. still dirty though.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arch by `-a, --arch` like this:

```
dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0 -j 4-a arm
```

Read more on man page by running `man dkms` or find it here:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/dkms.8.html